# Symfony Routing: How to define global requirements/constraints for wildcards?

Tags: php, symfony

Laravel has such feature as `Global Patterns` ([described here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)).

The concept in short: You can define pattern for a wildcard once, like this `Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+')` and use wildcard `{id}` in your route patterns without repeating yourself.

Now, I am trying to integrate `symfony/routing` component in my home-made framework. I see that wildcard patterns may be defined using an `An array of requirements` ([described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html)) for every route, and I can not find the way to declare them globally.

Is there such/similar feature in `symfony/routing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on your framework - you should be able to eventually collect all your routes (`\Symfony\Component\Routing\Route()` objects) in RouteCollection (`\Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection()` object). Those may be routes defined either by your framework or app based on your framework.

That's, basically, what you need to do in order to match your URIs with `\Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher()`.

Now, `RouteCollection` can take any requirements you want and add them to all the Routes in the collection.

So, all you need to do is:

Define your `global` `requirements` anyhow, anywhere you want, but eventually add them to your final routes collection, like this:

```
$globalRequirements = [
    'any' => '.*',
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    'ident' => '[A-Za-z0-9]+',
    'date' => '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',
    'year' => '[0-9]{4}',
];

/** @var RouteCollection $routes */
$routes->addRequirements($globalRequirements);
```

Simple!

Note: All existing `requirements` with same name, like `year` will be rewritten in this case. So you will have to add some custom logic, if you want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

you can not declare wildcard patterns globally.
But you could do something like this:

1. Declare your controller as a service
2. Create route instance
3. Assign route to your controller in pool

Read this it should give you a better look
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html

Then you can create something like loader and in this loader when loading you taged controller services add a custom route definition to your actions.

Something like this:

public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $routes = new RouteCollection();

```
    foreach ($this->pool->getControllers() as $controllerKey => $controller) {
            $route = new Route($pattern, $defaults, $requirements, $options, $host, $schemes, $methods, $condition);
            $routes->add($controllerKey . '.' . $actionKey, $route);
    }

    return $routes;
}
```

Its only an example, so you could figure it out how to create route instance.